# Neo4j - Load CSV with headers containing dots?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If my CSV file consists of headers with dots:
`column1.name, column2.age, column3.city` ...

How can I read them? Should I avoid dots?

```
LOAD CSV FROM "URL..." AS row RETURN row.`column1.name`, toInteger(row.`column2.age`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing form csv is usually something you do for initial creation of the graph. So I would not worry too much about what looks pretty as long as it gets the job done.

It is absolutely fine to have dots in the headers and you can use:

```
RETURN row.`column1.name` as name, row.`column.age` as age
```

If you want to avoid using back ticks use:

```
RETURN row['column1.name'] as name, row['column.age'] as age
```